# Timestamp duplication in column; is duplication expected?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
               timestamp   value
1    2014-02-14 14:27:00 51.8460
2    2014-02-14 14:32:00 44.5080
3    2014-02-14 14:37:00 41.2440
4    2014-02-14 14:42:00 48.5680
5    2014-02-14 14:47:00 46.7140
```

I convert the **timestamp to POSIX** the following way:

```
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="America/New_York")
```

After that when I print the contents of my dataframe it appears to be this way:

```
                    timestamp             value    
2014-02-14 14:27:00 "2014-02-14 14:27:00" "51.8460"
2014-02-14 14:32:00 "2014-02-14 14:32:00" "44.5080"
2014-02-14 14:37:00 "2014-02-14 14:37:00" "41.2440"
2014-02-14 14:42:00 "2014-02-14 14:42:00" "48.5680"
2014-02-14 14:47:00 "2014-02-14 14:47:00" "46.7140"
2014-02-14 14:52:00 "2014-02-14 14:52:00" "44.986"
```

**The code I'm using:**

```
  df <- read.csv(csv_filename, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="America/New_York")
  s <- xts(df, order.by = df$timestamp) #time series conversion
```

I'm not sure as of why xts function duplicates the timestamp.

Comment: I think it's because you tell `xts` to assign the timestamp to each row, which silently converts it to a `matrix` (therefore upconverting everything in it to a `character`). Perhaps you would prefer to use `xts(df$value, order.by=df$timestamp)`?

Comment: Get rid of the duplicates, but now I get: "Error in `$.zoo`(s, value) : 
  only possible for zoo series with column names"

Comment: I guess it is because the result is a date time object, but is not POSIX

Comment: The results is an `xts` object, and the contents are `character`. This is because when a `data.frame` is converted to a `matrix` (even if you did not intend for that), then the classes are "up-converted", where `character > POSIXct > numeric > integer > logical`. However, it appears that `POSIXt` is skipped, as shown by `str(as.matrix(d))`.

Comment: nvm.  Your first comment solved it. My error message happened in another function. If you post your suggestion I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically (often?), time-series are on vectors. When done to a `data.frame`, it is silently converted to a `matrix` which, in this cases, causes everything to be converted to `character` (even the POSIXct).

```
str(xts(df, order.by=d$timestamp))
# An 'xts' object on 2014-02-14 14:27:00/2014-02-14 14:47:00 containing:
#   Data: chr [1:5, 1:2] "2014-02-14 14:27:00" "2014-02-14 14:32:00" "2014-02-14 14:37:00" ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "timestamp" "value"
#   Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: America/New_York
#   xts Attributes:  
#  NULL
```

(Notice that the data is `chr`, or `character`.)

Instead, use `xts(df$value, order.by=df$timestamp)`, as it retains the numeric class:

```
str(xts(df$value, order.by=df$timestamp))
# An 'xts' object on 2014-02-14 14:27:00/2014-02-14 14:47:00 containing:
#   Data: num [1:5, 1] 51.8 44.5 41.2 48.6 46.7
#   Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: America/New_York
#   xts Attributes:  
#  NULL
```